# How to use if statement in mysql to add text to a string value

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to check if schoolid is 1, then add hyphen next year in two digit form to record.year

For example, if record.year = 1997, and schools.schoolid =1, then I would want record.year to return 1997-98.

```
$sqlquery = 'SELECT 
        record.year, 
        schools.school, 
        schools.schoolid, 
        sports.sport, 
        conferences.conference, 
        record.year 
    FROM 
        `record`,
        `schools`,
        `conferences`, 
        `sports` 
    WHERE 
        schools.schoolid = record.schoolid 
    AND 
        sports.sportid = record.sportid 
    AND 
        record.conferenceid = conferences.conferenceid';
```

Comment: And for `record.year = 1997, and schools.schoolid =5`, it should return `1997-02` ?

Comment: Oops, ignore the above, I hadn't seen the `schoolid=1` restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `record.year` is of type `INT`,

```
SELECT    
IF
(
   schools.schoolid = 1,
   CONCAT(record.year,'-',RIGHT(record.year+1,2)),
   record.year
) AS year,
schools.school,
....
```

if record.year is `varchar` just cast it to number when adding hyphen:

```
SELECT    
IF
(
   schools.schoolid = 1,
   CONCAT(record.year,'-',RIGHT(CAST(record.year AS SIGNED)+1,2)),
   record.year
) AS year,
schools.school,
....
```